# GPS error reasons and maximising errors

Tags: gps, error, microwave

I noticed that when using gps in mobile phone, I am positioned away from a wall if I stay very close to it. For example on a street with buildings on both sides, I usually get my location fix on the opposite side of the street than I'm actually on.

I'm guessing that can be explained by the building close to me resulting in a signal delay from satellites behind it (low-frequency microwave spectrum will not penetrate it that well), rather than signal from the front being reflected (this would result in locating me inside of the building instead).

Is that right or is there some more precise explanation?

Additionally, if I wanted to maximise the error for a single device using common materials, is there some simple solution that would achieve good result?

Comment: Define "maximise error". If you put it in a copper box, it won't get any answer at all, which is about as big an error as you can get.

Comment: Ok, I meant maximise displacement in a chosen direction.

Answer (score 1):

Any civilian GPS is unlikely to yield the accuracy the question implies. This is not merely due to limitations in the quality or accuracy of GPS modules, but the **inherent and by-design low precision data as available on civilian GPS signals** from the satellites.

After "Selective Availability" restrictions were turned off for civilian GPS in 2000 or so, the accuracy possible became about 10 meters with GPS data alone, and between 1.5 best case and 8 meters typical with WAAS and similar enhancements.

Typical single-chip GPS units (as used in smartphones) using such techniques thus achieve up to this degree of precision - which would still put you potentially across the road, or not, depending in sheer chance, at any given point in time.

Modern high-end **stand-alone** GPS devices do address this shortcoming in part by using Adaptive GPS and Differential GPS techniques, enhancing the precision of the received GPS signal using ground-based "beacons" and by combining GPS data with inertial navigation data as far as possible.

The culmination of such precision enhancing techniques is Relative Kinematic Positioning (RKP), which can achieve precision of the order of 10 cm, but given the processing and data requirements of such systems, it is unlikely that current mobile phones incorporate high precision RKP. If there are any such phones which do, that would be interesting to know.

Though this does not solve the specific problem stated in the question, hopefully it provides some insight into why **the desired results may be impractical**.